# beautiful soup with error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributes, nonetype

I have to say first that I m a total beginner concerning Beautifulsoup. 
I did try on several website to gather data (in this case the latest value of difficulty) in order to practice but I could not get any result/value besides this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

https://www.quandl.com/data/BCHAIN/DIFF-Bitcoin-Difficulty

here is the code that i am using:

```
quote_page = 'https://www.quandl.com/data/BCHAIN/DIFF-Bitcoin-Difficulty'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

value_box = soup.find('div', {'class':'latest-value'})
value = value_box.text
```

I've been looking for similar errors and it might be because the value_box is empty or None. However I do not know how to adapt it.

Thanks a lot for your support :)

Comment: `soup.find()` returns `None` if an element is not found.

Comment: So what should happen instead when `value_box` is none (not present in the HTML returned from the URL)?

Comment: You can always check `if value_box is not None`

Comment: That page uses AJAX to load the data. `urllib2` is not a browser and won't execute Javascript attached to a page, so the HTML you loaded doesn't contain the data you see. Just load the JSON from https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BCHAIN/DIFF/metadata?include%5B%5D=favorite&include%5B%5D=related_collections&include%5B%5D=latest_values instead. That's the URL that page uses to load the data into the browser.

Comment: How do you obtain the JSON from a website ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try doing the same using any browser simulator like selenium. Here is how you can deal with that:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome as browser
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

with closing(browser()) as wd:
    wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)
    wd.get('https://www.quandl.com/data/BCHAIN/DIFF-Bitcoin-Difficulty')
    item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".latest-value-item .latest-value")))[1]
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
2,874,674,234,420
```

Comment: thank you for your help. As said I'm new in it and I do not know how to install selenium in a notebook for python 2 any advices?